# How to compile C# code to 64 bit in Xamarin Studio on OS X?

Tags: 64-bit, xamarin-studio

I'm dealing with a large single text file (1.5 GB). 
I have a machine with 16 GB memory, but Xamarin Studio only allows me to compile things into 32-bit executables. So my 16 GB memory could not me utilized fully.

So my question is, how do I compile my code into 64-bit programs in Xamarin Studio in OS X? Are there other ways to break this memory limit set by mono for each process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't yet compile to 64bit or use 64bit native libraries with Xamarin.Mac unfortunately, it's still 32bit only, they are apparently working on it though.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin announced the Unified API 32/64 bit for Mac and iOS back in 8/19/2014, so the answer is now: yes.

Assuming you have a installed a 64-bit Mono (& compiler) framework on OS-X as the default install is still 32-bit in order to support GTK# applications. Within Xamarin studio you can change the Mono framework SDK to your 64-bit version that is being used to compile/run.